# Не выделяется память

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Установила виртуальную машину Ubuntu при помощи VirtualBox, но в процессе работы с ней, выяснила, что выделила недостаточно памяти. Это было исправлено, путем ввода команд через командную строку (основная ОС Windows 7), в настройках виртуального диска это значение  изменилось [image: введите сюда описание изображения], но на самой машине все осталось по-прежнему[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить? Как правильно можно изменить объем памяти на виртуальной машине?

Comment: Вот кстати интересный вопрос: можно ли увеличить размер раздела с Linux из самой системы.

Comment: Поправка, я нашла пропавшую память через gparted, а вот добавить ее к нужному разделу не могу(((

Comment: речь ведь про диск? а не про RAM?

Comment: да, про диск (ROM)

Comment: ROM - это не диск. что касается вопроса, то вам надо создать новый раздел и подключить его к системе.

Comment: Спасибо) так и сделаю) Напишите, пожалуйста, можно будет в этот новый раздел устанавливать программы?

Comment: Если машина нужна дальше не для "игр с разделами", то наверное, самым практичным будет снести ее и установить по новой, выделив как минимум гигов 100 под виртуальный диск, на который вы дальше будете все ставить. И не забудьте потом сделать общий для винды и виртуалки диск (насколько помню, в virtualbox manager это называется что-то вроде общей папки) и подключить его (удобно для обмена файлами между системами)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увеличив "жёсткий диск" ты НЕ увеличила раздел внутри этого "жёсткого диска" на котором стоит система. Лучше всего это сделать прогрузившись с [Gparted Live](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/latest/download) и мышкой растянув размер раздела до максимального.

Comment: Спасибо))) немного покопавшись расширила память через gparted) (а потом все снесла и заново установила, но уже выделив достаточно памяти))))

Comment: @Ann, ну тогда отметь ответ как правильный.

Comment: @Ann, да, на будущее. Под "памятью" обычно понимают оперативную памтья. Про винты говорят "место".

Comment: Премного благодарна)